# Scanner java: - how to "read" what type of data user entered?

Tags: java

I am very new to programming and what I started doing is writing a code that converts different units in metric system. For example, the program asks the user to enter x-amount of kilometer and then it converts that value to miles etc. Of course km & miles can only be positive values. However, I don't seem to get around of telling the program: "if entered value is an alphabetic value, then ask user to reenter the value." I seem to get it working for negative values, but not for alphabetic characters, please help.

**Here is my code:**

```
    //Method for converting kilometer to mile. Will be invoked in main method
    public static void KmToMiles(double k, double mi) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("convert kilometer to mile:");
    k = scan.nextDouble();
    mi = k / 1.609344;
    if(mi < 0) {
        do {
            System.out.println("Entered value can not be negative. Enter a positive value:");
            k = scan.nextDouble();
            mi = k / 1.609344;
        } while (mi < 0);
    }
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(mi);
        bd = bd.setScale(1, RoundingMode.CEILING);
        System.out.println((int) k + " kilometer(s) =: " + bd + " miles");
        System.out.println("*****************************************\n");
        scan.close();
}
```

Comment: But I am using _**nextDouble()_** @Andrew Li. Am I using it in a wrong place?

Comment: helpful SO post, see solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817826/how-to-check-the-data-type-validity-of-users-input-java-scanner-class

Comment: maybe the method `hasNextDouble()` would help... see its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble--) *"Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as a double value"*

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from [SO solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817826/how-to-check-the-data-type-validity-of-users-input-java-scanner-class):

```
while (!scan.hasNextDouble())
    {
        System.out.println("Input must be double, please reinput:");
        scan.next();
    }
```

[David Eck's book provides helpful examples of validation and also provides adaptations of scanner](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c1/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try using try catch error handling under InputMismatchException.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    int aIntValue = scanner.nextInt();
    //Double aDoubleValue = scanner.nextDouble();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    //handler-code
}
```

If you want to re-ask at the same call then use while loop.

```
while(true)
{
  try {
      int aIntValue = scanner.nextInt();
      //Double aDoubleValue = scanner.nextDouble();
      break;
  } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    //handler-code
  }
}
```